# Maven central vs Maven local

Tags: java, maven

Estoy creando un proyecto Java en [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans)  y estoy usando también [maven](/questions/tagged/maven)  para agregar las dependencias.

Casi siempre, me da varias opciones de las dependencias, no solamente en cuanto a las versiones, sino que en algunas pone al final `central` o `local`, como muestra la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- **¿Qué significa `central` y qué significa `local`?**
- **¿Qué implicaciones tendría usar una u otra para mi proyecto?**

Comment: No he usado maven con Netbeans... ¿Podrías ir a tu directorio HOME (`C:\Users\ACedano` o `/home/ACedano`) y ver si hay un directorio `.m2/repository/net.sf.jasperreports/6.4.3`? Puede que solo te indique que ya hay una copia descargada en tu repositorio local, pero en ese caso el POM no debería variar al escoger una ubicación u otra.

Comment: @SJuan76 yo instalé la dependencia `local` y efectivamente tengo una ruta `.ms2/repository/net/sf/jasperreports/6.4.3` con los archivos de la librería. ¿Significará eso que cuando se elige `local` te descarga todos los archivos en local? ¿Y cuando se elige `central`?

Comment: Maven siempre crea un repositorio local que cachea los artefactos de las dependencias, para no tener que bajarlos cada vez. Pero claro, se supone que la copia local será idéntica a la copia del repositorio central, así que no veo que sentido tiene hacer esa distinción. Puedo decirte que en Eclipse esa información no aparece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven tiene tres maneras de buscar las dependencias que necesita tu proyecto: local, remote y central.

**Local:**

El repositorio local es el que está en tu maquina. Por defecto, lo genera en una carpeta C:\Users[tuUsuario].m2\repository en Windows y \root.m2 en linux

**Central:**

Si al buildear Maven no puede encontrar en tu repositorio local la dependencia necesaria, va a ir a buscarla al repositorio central que esté seteado en tu settings.xml (Por defecto, busca en http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/). En caso de encontrarla, va a descargarla

**Remote:**

El remote funciona exactamente igual que el central, pero con la excepción de que se utiliza para acceder a repositorios que quizás son propios de tu empresa y/o organización, y no repositorios públicos como el anteriormente mencionado.